# How can the `.max` function in the dropdown list based on the sorted value?

Tags: python

I have a set of data with the date.

Data:

```
Date    Minor   Major   Sales
01/01/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     1000
01/01/2022  Tops    Clothes     100
08/01/2022  Shoes   Clothes     200
02/03/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     2000
02/03/2022  Tops    Clothes     200
02/03/2022  Shoes   Clothes     400
12/05/2022  Rakes   Garden  6
20/05/2022  Cooking     Kitchen     8
25/05/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     200
01/06/2022  Tops    Clothes     300
25/06/2022  Shoes   Clothes     400
25/06/2022  Turf    Garden  5
01/02/2022  Turf    Garden  1
01/02/2022  Hoses   Garden  2
02/04/2022  Turf    Garden  2
02/04/2022  Hoses   Garden  4
```

Using this method to get the month name from the month number. 
Input:

```
month_labels = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun', 7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug',9: 'Sep', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').dt.month

x= df['month'].apply(lambda x: month_labels[x])        

month_cat = list(x.unique())

sort_mm = sorted(month_cat, key=lambda m: datetime.strptime(m, "%b"))
```

Output:
print (sort_mm)

> > ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']

Data is able to sort when just print it but when put it into the dropdown's value, the `.max` is not functioning. (`.max` is using to let the dropdown list auto display the latest month in the listing.)

```
dcc.Dropdown(id='month_dd', value= x.max(),
                      options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                for x in sort_mm])
```

Output sequence will be:
Apr, Feb, Jan, Jun, Mar, May

How can the `.max` function in the dropdown list based on the sorted value?

Comment: It Is sorting your labels alphabetically. Your may use labels like '01 - Jan'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `max` of `df.month` *before* mapping it to the `month_labels` dictionary. I.e., set the `value` to

```py
value=month_labels[df['month'].max()]
```